# How to create a custom drop down box?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

Okay hi guys and girls.

I am looking to create a drop down box from a header, i want it to be custom i.e. a drawing.  I am just not 100% sure how to go about it, I have an idea of making a basic div with links for the drop down box and making it display empty until i click on a link making the css of the div style display to inline, 
I was just wondering if there is a better way to go about it? i also want the drop box to slide in from top to bottom and not just appear.

Any help will be great!

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you do me a favor and google for a tutorial instead?

Comment: Its not that i need help doing what i want to do, i just wanted to know if someone knew the best way

Comment: There never is "the best way" and you shouldn't ask for the best way, read the FAQ instead what to ask.